# 404 with post name permalinks

Tags: permalinks, htaccess, apache

So, I have a pretty common problem - I recently upgraded to Ubuntu Trusty Tahr from Precise, and I had to upgrade apache as a result. Now, my wordpress site is accessible, but I am unable to access any pages within my wordpress site.

So, for example, www.asjweddingsandevents.com works fine, but www.asjweddingsandevents.com/about gives a 404 ("about" is a page in wordpress). I've tried resetting the permalinks from "page name" to "plain" - when in the "plain" form, the pages are accessible via the `page_id=`-style link (e.g. http://www.asjweddingsandevents.com/?page_id=10), but when I set them back to "page name", they are inaccessible again.

I've double-checked that the apache rewrite mod is enabled (it's being used for other sites on the same server), and I've also double-checked the permissions of the `.htaccess` file, which are 666. The `.htaccess` file has the following contents:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

I'm not super fluent in wordpress configuration, and even worse, I'm not really an apache ninja, so some help on what I'm doing wrong (or, given this is a general error, how I can troubleshoot what's going wrong) would be much appreciated.

Comment: Two other things to note - I don't get a server error when I comment out the `<IfModule>` and `</IfModule>`, so the rewrite module is loaded. Additionally, if I try to navigate to http://www.asjweddingsandevents.com/?page_id=10 when "page name" permalinks are enabled, it redirects me to www.asjweddingsandevents.com/about, so I think it might be a wordpress problem and not an apache problem.

Comment: re save your permalink settings

Comment: @MarkKaplun I did try that, actually, numerous times (unless I'm doing something wrong). I change it from "Page Name" to "Plain", save it, and then change it back and re-save it. I've even tried removing the `.htaccess` file and re-saving the permalink settings (in order to get it to regenerate it), to no avail.

Comment: Also, I've noticed that when I change the permalink settings to 'plain', it sets the permalink in the 'Edit' view of the page, but if I set it to anything else (e.g. month/day), it stays as the page name.

Comment: turn off all plugins and try again, but most likely something is wrong with your apache

Comment: @MarkKaplun Yeah, plugin aren't causing the issue, either. I tried disabling all of them. :|

Answer (score 3):

I was able to figure out the problem, and for the sake of posterity, I'm posting the answer here. Basically, the new `apache2.conf` file that was added when I updated my web server had the following lines in it (my document root is `/var/www`):

```
<Directory /var/www/>                                                           
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks                                          
        AllowOverride None                                                      
        Require all granted                                                     
</Directory>
```

I replaced the `AllowOverride None` line with `AllowOverride all`, restarted apache, and the permalinks now work.

Hopefully this will aid someone in the future with a similar problem.

Comment: You saved my day!

Comment: You saved my week!